"user denied geolocation" in leaflet/leaflet-locatecontrol on some (mobile) devices/not asking for permissions
I am using leaflet 1.9.4 and leaflet-locatecontrol 0.79. My code is as follows:
function initmap() {
    // initialize map
    map = new L.Map('map', {
        tap: false,
        center: [52.520803, 13.40945],
        zoom: 17
    });

    const osmUrl='https://tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png';

    const osm = new L.TileLayer(
        osmUrl, {
            minZoom: 12,
            maxZoom: 28,
            maxNativeZoom: 19,
            useCache: true,
            crossOrigin: true }
    );

    // show OSM
    map.addLayer(osm);
    
    // create locate controls
    var lc = L.control.locate({
        setView: 'always',
        keepCurrentZoomLevel: true,
        locateOptions: {
            timeout: 30000,
            enableHighAccuracy: true
        },
        onLocationError: onLocationError,
        strings: {
            title: "follow"
        }
    }).addTo(map);
    
    // start Geolocation
    lc.start();

    // if geolocation fails, show error and set view to default
    function onLocationError(e) {
        alert(e.message);
        map.setView([52.520803, 13.40945]), 17);
    }

While the code seems to work as expected on most devices (f. e. Chrome 123 on Android 14, Firefox on Android 9, Opera on iOS), it fails in some constellations (f. e. Chrome 123 on Android 9 or Safari on iOS - same devices which work well with firefox or opera).
The expected behavior is, that the browser asks the user for permission to use geolocation and start geolocating him afterwards with updating the map to the users position. Instead it doesn't ask whether geolocation should be allowed and I get the alert immediatley, that the "user denied geolocation".
All browsers have the permission to use location services and the website is accessed via https.

Has a request for permission been denied previously for that site, in the affected browsers? AFAIK, browsers won't let you ask multiple times; if the user already declined previously, they might not get asked again. "All browsers have the permission to use location services" - general permission perhaps, but it might be restricted on a per-site basis, so go check if there are any such settings.

No, the error appears even when accessing the site for the first time.

I'm guessing the above code runs automatically, and is not directly tied to a user interaction (click on something, to trigger the whole process)? Then some browsers might probably block it based on that. (Should be easy enough to verify, if you create a small test page, that tries to invoke navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition() automatically, and another one that invokes it on a button click.)

Yes, this is supposed to run automaticly but your advice still helped me. In Chrome it helped not only to allow location services in general, but also to explicitly whitelist the website. Now it also works in all Chrome browsers on all test devices. I can only reproduce the error in Safari on iOS. Therefore I suspect that the code is fundamentally correct and it is a configuration problem of the end devices. Or maybe there is a code that Safari accepts?
